# get in the center of the composite? eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swt, composite

My purpose is to draw in the CENTER of the composite. Actually, I have an rcp view and I'm drawing some shapes inside it. this is the code that I use :

```
display = parent.getDisplay();
white= display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
parent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

// Create the ScrolledComposite to scroll horizontally and vertically
final ScrolledComposite sc =new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
sc.setExpandVertical(true);
sc.setMinHeight(100);
sc.setMinWidth(100);
sc.setSize(100,100);
Composite child = new Composite(sc,SWT.NONE);   
child.setLayout(new FillLayout());
child.layout(true);

parent.addListener (SWT.Resize,  new Listener () {
    public void handleEvent (Event e) {
        x = child.getBounds().width/2;
        y = child.getBounds().height/2;
        child.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
        dessin(gc); // to raw the circle
    }
    });
sc.getDisplay().update(); 
    }
});
```

I defined the view with a ratio (so when the view is empty I get the wanted size)...I don't know the exact size of the view since it can be resized by the user at anymoment, or when an editor is opened... So, my problem is how to draw just in the center of the view and keep the drawings in the center even if the view is resized... 
PS: Using (Point.x and point.y), I get (0,0) when the view appears first, then I get other values...
Pleaaaaaaaaaaaaaase help

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm really not sure what are you asking about.. But, when you'll try `control.getBounds()` you'll get `Rectangle` instance with `width` and `height` of `Control`. If you know the size, then centering is quite easy..

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that I don't want to set the composite's size myself and more important, when the view is resized, the rectangle.height and .width that I get are not ok.. since it can be scrolled, so I get the top part of the view, when I scroll down,I get the image...

Comment: So you want to have the circle in center of view part no matter how is real size of the canvas (where is user scrolled in)..?

Comment: yes, it is what I want to do...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getOrigin()` method on `ScrolledComposite`, which will return `Point` instance with the point in the content that currently appears in the top left corner of the scrolled composite. See docs [getOrigin method on ScrolledComposite](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html#getOrigin%28%29).

With that information and size of the component which you'll get from `getBounds()` method you can easily calculate the 'real' center.

Comment: origin is always {0,0}, sorry but I couldn't get what u mean exactly :(

Comment: well, the code that I've posted is the one that I'm using... It's simlpy drawing inside an rcp view... I just want to keep the drawing in the center even if the view is recised..

Comment: Actually, more precisely, I think he problem is that a restore down is not being detected, afer I maximize the window, I notice that x and y remain the same (as when it is still maximized)